# C++ Data File with extra empty line

Tags: c++, eof

I have data files with extra empty lines in them at the end. This is causing problems with reading in the data lines. I'm using:

while (datFile.good())

but .eof() didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

```
    while (datFile.good())
    {
        getline (datFile, line);

        istringstream liness(line);

        int z = 0;

        while (z <= index)
        {
            while (liness >> temp)
            {
                if (z == 0)
                {
                    values[0].push_back(atof(temp.c_str()));
                }

                if (z == index)
                {
                    values[1].push_back(atof(temp.c_str()));
                }

                cout << temp << endl;

                z++;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Just read the empty lines and throw them away later?

Comment: My program just sits there.

How would I "read the empty lines"?

The data is columnar in nature. Should I post more code?

Comment: Why don't you compare the string length after read and exit, once you start getting the zero length record.

Comment: I tried adding a if (line != "\n"), but that didn't work.

Comment: Your code should even fail when there are no empty lines at the end, because of the good old [`while(!eof)` error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/743214).

Answer (score 2):

Thou shalt use the stream's status after thy read!

You didn't post enough code to tell but input always looks something like this:

```
while (in >> data) {
    process(data);
}
```

Whether you use formatted input or unformatted input diesn't matter either. Also, `good()` is generally not that useful aabd `eof()` is only useful to suppress an error message: if you read failed it may be OK that it failed because you read all the data. It is never a useful condition to determine whether a read was successful: `eof()` can yield `true` although the read was successful.

Comment: `while (datFile >> ??)
{
    process(datFile);
}`

Comment: @user1187621 In your case it's actually `while(getline(datFile, line))`.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (getline (datFile, line))
{

    istringstream liness(line);

    // the rest of the loop is unchanged.
    ...
}
```